# Controller get null from dynamically added object in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I added a dynamically added object like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Province)
```

My model contains the Province properties but the view didn't show the object at the begining. I made it visible by .show() method.

However, in the controller, I found always the value for Province is null. How to make it accessible from dynamically added object like this?

Added:
my model looks like this:

```
public class Location
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State/Province")]
    public string Province { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Location.Add(location);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Province)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <div id="province_ddl">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.Province,
            Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
            "-- Select State/Province --"
            )
    </div>
    <div id="province_tb" style="display: none">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Province)
    </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Province)
    </div>
```

When I use dropdownlist, it will have right value for Province property. However, if I made textbox control visible, it won't have value i.e., got null value in the controller.

Comment: Do you get corresponding input fields for each of the Province properties? How does your model look like? How does your controller action look like? What objects are they taking as argument? What's *dynamic* in this scenario? You need to provide a lot more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 input fields in the same form with the same name (`Province` in your case).  Well, actually you can but only the value of the first will be sent to the controller. So if you keep the dropdown it will be the selected value of the dropdown that will always be sent to the controller. So basically you have to decide. You might disable one of the fields (by adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to it, could be done dynamically) to force only the value of the other to be sent.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any workaround? I thought if I could make the object hidden, it would work. If Razor engine recognizes the hidden dropdownlist, how to make a input field for addtional item which was not originally in the ddl list?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Razor, or ASp.NET MVC or whatever. That's pure HTML. You cannot have 2 fields with the same name within the same form. If you want to do this simply disable one of them (by adding the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to it) and thus only the value of the other field will be sent. Adding a CSS `display:none` has strictly no effect on the markup. It's only visual. You could have used a hidden field with exactly the same effect instead of trying to hide the field with CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I have to try hidden field way.